# ProgressDialog fechando antes da Segunda Activity abrir

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-intent

Tenho uma Activity chamada Login_Activity, quando o usuario fizer o login, eu quero que apareça um ProgressDialog, até que a outra Activity esteja totalmente carregada, pois como vou colocar algumas coisas pra executar no método onCreate da segunda Activity, a tela fica um tempo travada sem nada na tela para o usuario.

Segue a classe Principal Login_Activity...

```html
package com.example.patrickcamargo.rmpgseguros.Apresentacao;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.patrickcamargo.rmpgseguros.Conexao.Conexao;
import com.example.patrickcamargo.rmpgseguros.Conexao.ConexaoInterface;
import com.example.patrickcamargo.rmpgseguros.Modelo.ErrosBD;
import com.example.patrickcamargo.rmpgseguros.Modelo.JDialogCarregando;
import com.example.patrickcamargo.rmpgseguros.R;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class Login_Activity extends AppCompatActivity implements ConexaoInterface, Serializable{

    EditText txt_loginEmail, txt_loginSenha;
    Button btn_loginEntrar;
    Login_Activity login_activity;

    JDialogCarregando jDialogCarregando = new JDialogCarregando();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login_);

        login_activity = this; //VARIAVEL CRIADA PARA PASSAR O PARAMETRO PARA A CLASSE CONEXÃO
        txt_loginEmail = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txt_loginEmail);
        txt_loginSenha = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txt_loginSenha);
        btn_loginEntrar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_loginEntrar);

        btn_loginEntrar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                jDialogCarregando.inicializar(login_activity,"Carregando...");
                Conexao conexao = new Conexao(getApplicationContext(), login_activity);
                String parametrosUrl = "email=" + txt_loginEmail.getText() + "&senha=" + txt_loginSenha.getText();
                conexao.execute("TCC/json_logarCliente.php",parametrosUrl);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void depoisDownload(String result) throws JSONException {
        if( result == null) {
            //SE O RESULTADO FOR NULL, QUER DIZER QUE NÃO OBTEVE SUCESSO NA COMUNICAÇÃO COM O SERVIDOR
            //ENTÃO SE EXIBE A MENSAGEM DE ERROR
            Conexao conexao = new Conexao(this, this);
            conexao.exibeSemConexao(this);
        } else if (result.contains("ERROR")) {
            //ERROR 147 QUER DIZER QUE O LOGIN ESTÁ ERRADO, ENTÃO RECEBE-SE A MENSAGEM DE DADOS INCORRETOS
            ErrosBD errosBD = new ErrosBD();
            Toast.makeText(this,errosBD.ErrosBD(result),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            txt_loginSenha.setText("");
        } else {
            //CRIANDO VARIAVEIS PARA PASSAR COMO PARAMETROS PARA A ACTIVITY PRINCIPAL
            String[] vt_carro = new String[10], vt_placa = new String[10], vt_cor = new String[10], vt_ano = new String[10];
            String p_email = null, p_nome = null, p_cpf = null, p_rg = null, p_cnh = null, p_id = null;

            //CRIANDO ARRAY COM O RESULTADO
            JSONArray minhaArray = new JSONArray(result);
            JSONObject obj;
            for (int i = 0; i < minhaArray.length(); i++) {
                obj = new JSONObject(minhaArray.getString(i));
                if (i == 0) {
                    p_nome = obj.getString("Nome");
                    p_email = obj.getString("Email");
                    p_rg = obj.getString("RG");
                    p_cnh = obj.getString("CNH");
                    p_cpf = obj.getString("CPF");
                    p_id = obj.getString("FK_Pessoa");
                } else {
                    vt_carro[i-1] = obj.getString("Marca") + " - " + obj.getString("Modelo");
                    vt_placa[i-1] = obj.getString("Placa");
                    vt_cor[i-1] = obj.getString("Cor");
                    vt_ano[i-1] = obj.getString("Ano");
                }
            }
            //PASSANDO OS PARAMETROS PARA A ACTIVITY PRINCIPAL
            Intent intent = new Intent(Login_Activity.this, MenuInicial.class);
            intent.putExtra("p_nome", p_nome);
            intent.putExtra("p_email", p_email);
            intent.putExtra("p_cpf", p_cpf);
            intent.putExtra("p_cnh", p_cnh);
            intent.putExtra("p_rg", p_rg);
            intent.putExtra("vt_carro", vt_carro);
            intent.putExtra("vt_placa", vt_placa);
            intent.putExtra("vt_cor", vt_cor);
            intent.putExtra("vt_ano", vt_ano);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
        jDialogCarregando.finalizar();
    }
}
```

Segue a classe que exibe o Progress Dialog

```html
package com.example.patrickcamargo.rmpgseguros.Modelo;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;

public class JDialogCarregando {
    private ProgressDialog progress;

    public void inicializar(Context context, String messageConexao)
    {
        progress = new ProgressDialog(context);
        progress.setMessage(messageConexao);
        progress.setCancelable(false);
        progress.show();
    }
    public void finalizar()
    {
        progress.dismiss();
    }

}
```

E por fim, a segunda Activity que sera chamada

```html
package com.example.patrickcamargo.rmpgseguros.Apresentacao;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import com.example.patrickcamargo.rmpgseguros.Modelo.JDialogCarregando;
import com.example.patrickcamargo.rmpgseguros.R;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class MenuInicial extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    JDialogCarregando jDialogCarregando = new JDialogCarregando();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu_inicial);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        Intent intent = this.getIntent();
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_inicial, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
            // Handle the camera action
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
```

Se tivesse um jeito de chamar o método jDialogCarregando.finalizar() somente quando a outra activity tivesse sendo executada ajudaria....

Answer (score 1):

A tela na segunda `activity` fica travada porque, de fato, está carregando alguma coisa. Você deve inicializar seu `Progress` na segunda `activity` da mesma forma que o fez na primeira.

Perceba que ao enviar os parâmetros via `intent` você finaliza o `progress` e desta forma não tem como ele ficar rodando enquanto a outra `activity` carrega. Assim, quando você fizer o pedido para exibir a segunda `activity` ela já estará  executando. O que você deve fazer é utilizar seu método do `Progress` novamente:

Declarando sua função:

```
JDialogCarregando jDialogCarregando = new JDialogCarregando();
```

E depois chamando:

```
jDialogCarregando.inicializar(MenuPrincipal.this, "Carregando...");
```

Depois só finalizar sua função aonde você acha que termina o carregamento:

```
jDialogCarregando.finalizar();
```